# Can we use groovy templates with Spring boot

Tags: groovy, spring-boot

I have application that I need to migrate with Spring boot. In my html files I have following codes that are not supported by thymeleaf, So is there any way I can use this same html and migrate to spring boot?

```
#{if redirectCount && redirectUrl}
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="${redirectCount}; url=${redirectUrl}" />
        #{/if}

<span class="copyright">&{'copyright'}</span>

#{extends 'main.html' /}
#{include '_header.html'/}
```

Comment: https://spring.io/blog/2014/05/28/using-the-innovative-groovy-template-engine-in-spring-boot

Comment: The answer is not clear to me. In my current application I have all html files that use above attached code .. so what will be best way to migrate such code with spring boot without making much code changes on the UI side.

Comment: Can anyone please help with an appropriate answer??

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, I am currently working on Groovy, Groovy-Template and Spring-Boot for experiments. I used that technics in a small appliation: https://github.com/MichaelHegner/financial-calculator